# Angular ng options default select value

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my 'view file'

```
<select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" 
                        ng-options="selection.id as selection.name for selection in selections track by selection.id"></select>
```

And this in my controller

```
$scope.currentSelected = 1;
$scope.selections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name #1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Name #2'
    }
];
```

However, the select options is blank and I want it to be in this example "Name #1". What am I missing here?

Comment: Remove `track by selection.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

track by works well with array. If you want it to be by id then you should use `selection.id as selection.name for selection in selections`

Remove `track by selection.id` and it should work fine.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.currentSelected = 1;
    $scope.selections = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Name #1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Name #2'
    }];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.id as selection.name for selection in selections"></select>
</body>

</html>
```